# Specifying different number of output plots/tables (Shiny app)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to give the user option to select which plots/tables he/she wants to see at the end of an analysis.
All the plots are produced from one dataset and include time series plots, boxplots, histograms etc.
The questions I stumbled upon are

1. Do I use one or multiple `plotOutput("Plot",....)` element? So far I have been arranging plots in one figure so one `plotOutput` was sufficient
2. Do I use the predefined height, as in `plotOutput("Plot",height = "1800px"`)?
   If the number of figures varies this creates empty space, I would like to avoid it.
3. How to add Tables with results?

Any comments would be very appreciated, Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you plots in conditionalPanel's to deselect them.

For this you will need 1. multiple plotOutput's.
2. When everything is wrapped in a fluidRow there won't be any empty space.
3. See the following example and: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/tableOutput.html

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Plot selection"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    materialSwitch(inputId="switch1", label = "Show plot 1", value = TRUE, status = "primary"),
    materialSwitch(inputId="switch2", label = "Show plot 2", value = TRUE, status = "primary"),
    materialSwitch(inputId="switch3", label = "Show plot 3", value = TRUE, status = "primary"),
    materialSwitch(inputId="switch4", label = "Show plot 4", value = TRUE, status = "primary")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch1", box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch2", box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250))),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch3", box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250))),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch4", box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250))),
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(500), col2 = rnorm(500), col3 = rnorm(500), col4 = rnorm(500))

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
plot(df$col1, col="red", main="Plot 1")
  })

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  plot(df$col2, col="green", main="Plot 2")
})

output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
  plot(df$col3, col="blue", main="Plot 3")
})

output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
  plot(df$col4, col="black", main="Plot 4")
})

output$table <- renderDataTable(df)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit ----------------------------------------

Here is a pure shiny version:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Plot selection"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 checkboxInput(inputId="switch1", label = "Show plot 1", value = TRUE),
                 checkboxInput(inputId="switch2", label = "Show plot 2", value = TRUE),
                 checkboxInput(inputId="switch3", label = "Show plot 3", value = TRUE),
                 checkboxInput(inputId="switch4", label = "Show plot 4", value = TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch1", plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch2", plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch3", plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switch4", plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),
        column(12,
               dataTableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(500), col2 = rnorm(500), col3 = rnorm(500), col4 = rnorm(500))

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df$col1, col="red", main="Plot 1")
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df$col2, col="green", main="Plot 2")
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df$col3, col="blue", main="Plot 3")
  })

  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df$col4, col="black", main="Plot 4")
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(df)

}

# shinyApp(ui, server)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For further information see:

https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html
https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/materialSwitch.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Hope it works with the rest of my app based so far on sidebarLayout/Panel. Most likely I have to rebuild it within the shinydashboard, correct?

Comment: No, shinydashboard was just personal preference - see my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pure shiny code doesn't work for me, I get the error: "Error in box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: Called shinyApp twice (copy, paste). Runs ok now?

Comment: Maybe someone else can reproduce the error? - runs fine on my machine.. (see picture)

Comment: It runs! After loading the 'shinydashboard' and 'shinyWidgets' packages all works fine, thanks!

Comment: uh.. I forgot to delete the "box"- function from shinydashboard. see another edit